# One-time pad app for the masses

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, encryption

I am looking for a dead-easy [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) suite of applications for at least Linux/Mac/Windows.

Requirements:

- Feature to easily create a random pad DVD (or at least ISO image)
- Decryption of text or files
- Makes it easy to keep track of what pad I gave to who, and decrypt using the right one
- Keep track of what portions of the pad have been used already, so that the same portion is never used twice
- Refuse to encrypt if the pad is not long enough anymore
- Open source
- Usable by anyone, GUI as intuitive as possible.

Comment: Maybe you can start with Steve Gibson's [Perfect Paper Passwords](https://www.grc.com/ppp.HTM) and use his Windows implementation or follow his links to implementations.